# How to get the level of a parent node with an attribute that matches a string?

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have this XML file (it is a Freeplane MindMap I want to transform to markdown):

```
            <node TEXT="About exceptions" LOCALIZED_STYLE_REF="AutomaticLayout.level,2" ID="ID_1944432951" CREATED="1515603952224" MODIFIED="1515603952225">
                <node TEXT="- runtime exceptions (*runtime exceptions*) and its subclasses `:" ID="ID_1822312851" CREATED="1515603952233" MODIFIED="1515603952233">
                    <node TEXT="  - ArrayIndexOutofBounds" ID="ID_1897172344" CREATED="1515603952233" MODIFIED="1515603952233"/>
```

...

```
            <node TEXT="Collections" LOCALIZED_STYLE_REF="AutomaticLayout.level,2" ID="ID_1932847832" CREATED="1515603952454" MODIFIED="1515603952460">
                <node TEXT="Classes" LOCALIZED_STYLE_REF="AutomaticLayout.level,3" ID="ID_1207794388" CREATED="1515603952464" MODIFIED="1515603952464">
                    <node TEXT="`Map` is specific..." ID="ID_817824121" CREATED="1515603952464" MODIFIED="1515603952464"/>
```

I need to add indentation to my output according to **how many** ancestors there are between the current node and its ancestor (a *header* node) selected by an attribute.

**The header node (or *depth reference node*)**

The matching ancestor's attribute is `LOCALIZED_STYLE_REF` and it must start with `AutomaticLayout.level,` (followed by any number: `AutomaticLayout.level,1` e.g.)

So I need to add tab characters according to the difference between something like:

- `count(ancestor::*)` on the matching parent node
- `count(ancestor::*)` on the current node

I tried the code below but with no success (I don't know how to get the `lastHeaderLevel` value) :

```
<xsl:call-template name="addIndentation">
    <xsl:with-param name="currentNodeLevel" select="count(ancestor::*)" />
</xsl:call-template>

<!-- Template to calculate difference between current node's depth and last header's depth  -->
<xsl:template name="calculateIndentation">
    <xsl:param name="currentNodeLevel">0</xsl:param>
    <xsl:call-template name="numberSign">
        <xsl:with-param name="howMany" select="$currentNodeLevel - $lastHeaderLevel - 1"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Template to change text indentation according to level from last header  -->
<xsl:template name="appendIndentationToOutput">
    <xsl:param name="howMany">0</xsl:param>
    <xsl:if test="$howMany &gt; 0">
        <!-- Add 1 number signs (tab) to output. -->
        <xsl:text>&#x9;</xsl:text>
        <!-- Print remaining ($howMany - 1) number signs. -->
        <xsl:call-template name="addIndentationToOutput">
            <xsl:with-param name="howMany" select="$howMany - 1"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

The **depth** between nodes can vary from `0` to `n`

How can I get the correct **depth** between a *header* node and the current node using  XSLT v1.0 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most recent header will be

```
ancestor::*
  [starts-with(@LOCALIZED_STYLE_REF, 'AutomaticLayout.level,')]
  [1]
```

I'd define a variable `$current-header` with that value, and then the difference of depth becomes, as you expect, a matter of

```
count(ancestor::*) - count($current-header/ancestor::*)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I actually get something but the `<xsl:value-of select="count($current-header/ancestor::*)"/>` fails if there is no ancestor available. So I tried to put an if statement prior to it but it does not work: `<xsl:if test="current-header != "">`. What should I put in the `test` string ?

Comment: I'd use something like `count($current-header) > 0`; others may prefer just `$current-header`.  Your immediate problem is that you omitted the dollar sign in the reference to the variable; a second problem is that you appear to be conflating existence with the possession of a string value other than ''.

Comment: I'm a little surprised at the failure you report; I would have expected count() to return zero if $current-header does not exist.  What error message are you getting and what XSLT processor are you using?

Comment: Hi, I finally manage to make it work using a variable `lastHeaderCount` initialized to `count(ancestor::*[starts-with(@LOCALIZED_STYLE_REF, 'AutomaticLayout.level,')][1])`. After if its value is greater than 0, I can use your code and it works. Thanks !